# Why is my Webpack DevServer, after start, redirecting from localhost:3000/webpack to localhost/webpack?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack, wamp

Why is my webpackdev server, after start, redirecting from localhost:3000/webpack to localhost/webpack ?

I am using WAMP server to develop custom wordpress theme, and each project has it's own folder, one of folders
is called **'webpack'** hence I want to open project at localhost:3000/webpack for development, but it does not work.

This is my repo (this repo is basically wordpress theme folder): https://github.com/BiezdarJS/webpack-wordpress

Below the code for devServer config:

```
devServer: {
    // static: {
    //   directory: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.php'),
    // },

    port: 3000,
    open: ['webpack'],
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example